# Calling ASMX WebMethod from jQuery - responseText is blank xhr.status = "error"

Tags: jquery, asmx, webmethod, responsetext

Am completely flummoxed.

1. jquery v1.5.2 Firefox 3.6.16 ASMX
2. List item
3. Web service written in VS 2010, .Net Framework 3.5
4. Hosted on local computer's VS 2010 Development web server OR ON
5. Main web server running IIS 7.5 on Windows Web Server 2008 R2

Both local dev web server and the main production web server exhibit same behavior

1. The web service works well when invoked from the browser.
2. I get the list of methods.
3. I can click on the method name
4. I can click the Invoke button and the method is invoked and the result is returned

When my jquery page calls the same web method, the error function is fired with the following status fields

readyState : 0
responseText : ""
status : 0
statusText : "error"
error : function()

**My jQuery portion**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://localhost:1272/ndtvservices.asmx/HelloWorld',
                        data: '{}',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(msg) {
                                 alert("success " + msg) ;
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                                 var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                                 alert(err.Message) ;
                        }
                    });
               });
        </script>
```

**My web method**

Imports System.Web.Services

Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

Imports System.ComponentModel

Imports System.Web.Script.Services

Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
' _

_

_
 _

Public Class Service1
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

```
'<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=False, XmlSerializeString:=False)> _
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim s As String = "Hello World"
    Dim sReturn As String = js.Serialize(s)
    Return sReturn
End Function
```

End Class

My web config under system.web has these entries as I read on SO somewhere

```
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet"></add>
      <add name="HttpPost"></add>
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
```

_

I have tried with the above statement commented and uncommented.

As I understand this, this should not be required for a non asp.net ajax page calling this method.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a bunch

Best wishes

Iyer

Comment: What port is your service running on? You might be running into cross-domain issues if your service is not running on the same port as your client application.

Comment: You dont need to put the the full url just..`url:"ndtvservices.asmx/HelloWorld"` is enough

Comment: njebert : THanks for taking the time out to respond.  My dev system runs the asp.net dev server, of course.  And the port keeps changing - that's the reason I mention the fill http://localhost:1272 in the "url".  The web service and the jQuery are running on my local machine or on the same server.  In any case both my dev system and my produciton web server are on the same corporate windows domain - so, hopefully, there should be no cross-domain issues.

Comment: TheSuperTramp: Thanks for the suggestion : How would I specify the port number, in that case?  url:"ndtvservices.asmx:1272/HelloWorld"?  I will try that and report. Appreciate your taking the time out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should not be manually JSON serializing the response in your service method.  ASP.NET already does that for you automatically.  All you need is:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
  Return "Hello World"
End Function
```

And ensure that your service is decorated with the ScriptService attribute (my VB.NET is pretty rusty, so this might be off a little):

```
<ScriptService()> _
Public Class ndtvservices Inherits WebSerivce
```

Also, I would avoid using the fully qualified URI in $.ajax()'s url parameter.  This should be all you need:

```
url: '/ndtvservices.asmx/HelloWorld'
```

Finally, if you're using ASP.NET 3.5 or later, [ASP.NET wraps the JSON response in a ".d" object](http://encosia.com/2009/02/10/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/) to protect against a particular security issue concerning JSON arrays.  You'll want to "dot" into that wrapper object in your success callback like this:

```
success: function(msg) {
  alert("success " + msg.d) ;
}
```

Comment: Yes, yes, yes - all of you were right.  This is so super brilliant.

Comment: Thanks a super million.  Three days of intense frustration.  Completely fixed by all of you people.  Most generous of you to spend your time to answer my question.

Comment: I have never received a response leave alone a solution so fast anywhere else.  I am not going anywhere else anymore and I am going to try and contribute and help people - I don't know much, though!

Comment: Dave : Thanks a million.  You've saved me from more and more frustration!!  Your suggestions of not using the full host name worked as did the suggestion of doing away with the JavaScriptSerializer.  Not to check if I am actually getting JSON or not.

Comment: Dave : Thanks a million.  You've saved me from more and more frustration!!  Your suggestions of not using the full host name worked as did the suggestion of doing away with the JavaScriptSerializer.  Not to check if I am actually getting JSON or not.

Comment: Dave : If I had to use a port other that the standard 80, how would I write this url?  I can't write 1272:/ndtvservices.asmx/HelloWorld, can I?

Comment: If your service is hosted within the project that contains the page you're calling it from, using `/ndtvservces.asmx` as the url is okay.  For example, if your jQuery code appears on `http://localhost:1272/Default.aspx`, `/ndtvservices.asmx` automatically implies `http://localhost:1272/ndtvservices.asmx`

Comment: Understood and thanks for the explanation.  But the jQuery code is a temporary measure.  The web service will be standalone and be used as a supplier of data to any consumer.  The first consumer will, hopefully, be an Android app written in Titanium.  I will have to use the full host name then.  Will cross that bridge when I come to it.  Thanks, again